# Construct a generic type through reflection given the type of another object

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I'm passing a type to a method and creating an object based on that type. Assume `argType` is a `Type` and passed to the method as a parameter.

```
var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Single(a => a.GetName().Name == "MyAssembly");
var newType = assembly.GetTypes().SingleOrDefault(x => x.FullName == argType.FullName + "Suffix");
var newObject = Activator.CreateInstance(newType);
```

This works fine for most objects, but if I pass a type with a generic sub type (e.g. `MyClass<MyType>`), it fails [Assume the goal is to set `newObject` to a `MyClassSuffix<MyType>`].

How could the code above be improved so that generic types (ending with "Suffix") can also be created? I looked at the `FullName` property for such types which contain substrings like `'1[[`. I'd rather not do regex parsing to append "Suffix" before these characters begin. I'm thinking there is a better way.

Comment: Just a thought, I believe dynamic keyword was created to solve this complication.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `MakeGenericType` method if you have instance of both types i.e the generic class and the generic type parameter :

```
// assuming you have a generic class named Class<> 
// taking one generic type parameter
Type generic = typeof(MyClassSuffix<>);
Type typeParameter = typeof(MyClass);
Type genericInstance = generic.MakeGenericType(typeParameter);
```

and then:

```
object o = Activator.CreateInstance(genericInstance);
```

In your case you have `generic` as `newType` and you would need to figure out which type you need to pass as type parameter and it should work.

Read the following [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-examine-and-instantiate-generic-types-with-reflection) for detailed instructions on this topic:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-examine-and-instantiate-generic-types-with-reflection

### UDPATE:

You can get generic type parameters too following way

```
    var newType = assembly.GetTypes().SingleOrDefault(x => x.FullName == argType.FullName + "Suffix");
     if(newType.IsGenericType)
     {
        // Get the generic type parameters or type arguments.
        Type[] typeParameters = t.GetGenericArguments();

        // Construct the type Dictionary<String, Example>.
        Type constructed = newType.MakeGenericType(typeParameters);
     }
```

If you are having a closed type then you can instantiate it same way like a normal class. See the following example:

```
public class GenericClass<Int>
{

}
```

Now we can generate an instance of it like:

```
 Type t = typeof(GenericClass<int>);
 object o = Activator.CreateInstance(y);
 Console.WriteLine(o);
```

[DEMO Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5QkUOI)

Comment: Thanks. This is good to know if I want to create a generic type, but my question was more about figuring out whether the parameter (i.e. `argType`) is generic or not and creating a non-generic or generic suffix'ed object based on that. I can't hard code `MyClassSuffix<>` as the passed type parameter can be anything (i.e. not just `MyClass`)

Comment: @user246392 you can do that as well using `IsGenericType` method on type

Comment: this will give you idea how you can proceed using the instance of `Type` ,

Comment: My original issue was if `argType.FullName` returns a generic type name, adding "Suffix" to the end returns null for `newType` since "Suffix" must be added before `'1[[` in its `FullName`. In your example (after the update), `newType` is null and calling `newType.IsGenericType` throws an exception.

Comment: So you are talking about creating a new class with Suffix post fix ? if that's what you are asking it's not that trivial, reflection uses existing types in assembly, it can't generate new ones completely i guess

Comment: the following might help for that : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/93322/generating-a-class-dynamically-from-types-that-are-fetched-at-runtime

Comment: and read the following for your case, it would give you idea what you need to do : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/4xxf1410%28v%3dvs.100%29